# How do I set up a OSX 10.7.5 environment for HID development in Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, hid

How do I set up a OSX 10.7.5 environment for HID development in Java - Eclipse

I am trying to write a small app that will interface with the Teensy board (HID). I am working in Java using Eclipse. Anyway I have spent the last few days trying to figure out how to configure my environment with the appropriate "native library". 
I have downloaded the hidapi-0.7.0.zip https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/downloads 
also the files from http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/downloads/list (they are "wrappers" to the native library.

Anyway I am totally out of my league when it comes to installing these on my Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 MacBook. I have read and re-read the sparse documentation and can not figure out what to put where, or how to "build" things if necessary, etc.

I keep reading things about how to build the library's i.e. http: //code.google.com/ p/javahidapi/wiki/ ReadMe 
Do I have to build them?  I assume this is if you want to build from the source files but they do have .jar included.  Even if I figure out how to build them, where would I put the result.

Anyway hopefully someone can point me to some directions to do this. I have searched for them and have not found anything.

Comment: OK, finally got it to work.

Comment: I was able to find a file called libhidapi-jni-64.jnlib from http://tinyurl.com/ac2pyya I needed to change the name, just drop the "-64" put it into my java library path "/Library/Java/Extensions" along with a previously obtained hidapi-1.1.jar and I was good to go.  I'm assuming you could build your own libhidapi-ini.jnlib with the other code I was able to obtain but I never figured out how to do that.